# SQL - Selecting a customer that only bought 1 type of product on a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, distinct

I need to find out how many **pencils** were bought on 2017-01-01 by people that only bought 1 other type of product prior to buying **pencils**. (e.g. bought only **notebooks** beforehand)
This is what I have, that so far shows many who bought one type of product beforehand, so what I am missing is how many **pencils** they bought on the 2017-01-01:

```
SELECT 
c.name, 
s.units_sold AS Sold,
s.product_id

FROM 
sales AS s
INNER JOIN customers AS c
ON c.id=s.customer_id
GROUP BY c.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.product_id) = 1
```

I tried to look at similar questions without success.
Hope my question is clear :/

Thanks!

Comment: You should show sample data or at least the sample data layout.  Desired results is useful too.  Important information, such as the date field and the name of the product is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a very strange question.  But if I read literally, then you would seem to want something like this:

```
select sum(s.units_sold)
from sales s
where s.product_id = 'pencil' and
      s.date = '2017-01-01' and
      1 = (select count(distinct s2.product_id)
           from sales s2 
           where s2.customer_id = s.customer_id and 
                 s2.date < s.date
          );
```

Comment: Not only you understood my question, you nailed it! Thank you so much. I had to play around with it because I needed something slightly different, but that really helped!

Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's query is legit, although it seem to have a flaw: it would be executing the subquery as many times, as the number of customers are.
That's heavy.

Just remember that SQL is a declarative language, thus you not going to tell the engine how it should do the things - just declare what you need.

Thus, it might be thought through the way like:

1. I need to run my aggregate query on subset of customers.
2. So I'm going to determine this subset first: ones who had exactly one purchase; of any product other that pencil; prior to the given date
3. Once I have this set of customers, I can address their purchases of: exactly pencils; exactly on given date

Here, in first iteration (!), your query become pretty obvious (I'll be using Gordon's notation):

```
SELECT sum(s.units_sold)
FROM sales s
WHERE s.product_id = 'pencil' AND
      s.date = '2017-01-01' AND
      s.customer_id IN (
          SELECT s2.customer_id
          FROM sales s2
          WHERE s2.date < '2017-01-01'
          GROUP BY s2.customer_id
          HAVING count(DISTINCT s2.product_id) = 1
      );
```

I didn't really checked it, but I hope you got the idea - in this case, it is reduced to two-pass: one to get the subset of Customers that meet the given criteria, second to make the aggregation on their operations that are meeting given conditions.